# Getting mouse position in assembly TASM

Tags: assembly, mouse, calculator, tasm

I'm taking a course in assembly language and I'm required to make a calculator with (GUI?) and of course use the mouse to choose the numbers and so on ...

I'm almost done but I'm stuck, how can I get the position of the mouse? I know that I have to use AX=3 and INT33 and that the values of the coordinates will be stored in CX & DX. Now, the layout of the numbers is 3x3, how can I check if that particular position equals 4?

Comment: What is your OS? Is it dos, windows or something more?

Comment: If you're using INT 33, then you'll need to use the DOS references as that's the DOS mouse interface.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand? I've initiated the mouse and I can use it and see it moving.

Comment: The quick answer is to compare the returned mouse position with the positions you used to draw the numbers on the screen, but are you working in DOS or Windows XP?

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how to compare the rows and columns since three numbers (1,2,3) have the same row number. I'm getting lost lol

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an emulator that doesn't have ms-dos, this COULD be a very big problem. However since you said you're taking a course, the emulator probably has ms-dos.

Int 33h is a mouse handling event with the register ax as the input. Output results may vary depending on what graphics mode you have on (40x85, 320x200, Ext). Here are some of the basics that you will need to know.

1. **mov ax, 0000h:** Resets driver (may wanna do this first)
2. **mov ax, 0001h:** Show cursor
3. **mov ax, 0002h:** Hide cursor
4. **mov ax, 0003h:** Return cursor position
5. **mov ax, 0004h:** Set cursor position
6. **mov ax, 001Ah:** Set mouse sensitivity
7. **mov ax, 001Bh:** Get mouse sensitivity

In this syntax your asking to get the cursor position [No. 4]. You first need to but ax as 0003h. The return values are CX (horizontal position (x)), DX (vertical position (y)), and BX (button status). This infomation can be found [here.](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_33-3.html)